# Why is this python regular expression matching only one character, instead of the desired words?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the title, which is all in uppercase, from a text document. I want to avoid a long dashed sequence and some acronyms like `NOM-059-SEMARNAT 2010` that appear around the title; there may also be some other characters to exclude.

In order to accomplish this goal, I used the `findall` function in the python module `re` (under python 2.7.7, in `spyder`, windows 8.1).  This is the regular expression I used:

```
(?!(?:[- ]{2,}|NOM\-059\-SEMARNAT))([A-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚÑ:;¿\?\(\)\-\+\. ,]{10,})
```

I am getting many good matches, but also a few like this (in which the "N" has been skipped):

> OM-059-SEMARNAT-2010 (SEMARNAT, 2010). P

How can I avoid these bad matches?

A sample of the document I am scanning with this pattern is as follows:

> ---------------------------------------------  Congreso Mexicano
>   RELACIÓN ENTRE EL TAMAÑO DEL FOROFITO Y LA RIQUEZA DE EPÍFITAS EN LOS
>   PANTANOS DE CENTLA, TABASCO  Dwers Aasrd Jxcxéas Lóasd1*, Rasdé de
>   Jawdúz Rasdw Vasde1 Instituto de Ciencias Biologicas, Universidad de
>   Ciencias y Artes de Chiapas  awdsd.w@hlksajk.com   Las plantas
>   epífitas son poco comunes en manglares, no epífitas y las
>   características de los forofitos de Rhizophora mangle, especie
>   amenazada de acuerdo a la NOM-059-SEMARNAT-2010 (SEMARNAT, 2010); en áreas
>   de la reserva Pantanos de Centla, al noroeste de Tabasco. Se evaluó la
>   relación entre La riqueza de epífitas estuvo significativamente
>   relacionada con la cobertura de raíz y DAP de los forofitos. Las zonas
>   I y III de los forofitos fueron las más similares y compartieron 47%
>   del total de las especies. La zona I, que son las Palabras clave:
>   Epífitas vasculares, distribución vertical, composición, Rhizophora
>   mangle, raíces aéreas. ID: 96 lunes, 20 de abril de 2015, 3:30:00 PM,
>   Sala: 8 Eje temático: Ecología de Comunidades
>
> ---

Comment: Could you please precise? https://regex101.com/r/oF9hR9/1

Comment: If you know there are sequences of dashes before the title, why not use those as an "anchor"? `-{10,}.+?\n([^a-z]+\b)+` looks for "dashes, some text, a new line, some uppercase words."

Comment: Group 1 (the part of the string that matches the part of the regex in parentheses) then equals `RELACIÓN ENTRE EL TAMAÑO DEL FOROFITO Y LA RIQUEZA DE EPÍFITAS EN LOS PANTANOS DE CENTLA, TABASCO `. You can get rid of the trailing whitespace with `.strip()`.

Comment: I am getting in most cases a good match finding the title in uppercase.  The thing is how to avoid things I don't want like the dashes and the NOM-059... which are showing in my found list, and worst, they appear incomplete!!!!!

Comment: i'm confused.  you say you want to avoid the acronym, but then you complain that your RE hasn't caught the entire acronym.  shouldn't you be designing your RE to catch *only* the title -- and not the acronym?

Comment: Not complaining, confused! I wanted to skip it and failed,  partially. Don't understand why. In any avent what I want is a clean list of titles in the uppercase chunk at the head of many summaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have enough constraints that would make this work.
You have to roll-yer-own boundaries and set up pseudo anchors.

Compressed:

```
 # (?<![A-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚÑ:;¿?()\-+.,])((?!(?:NOM-059-SEMARNAT))[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÑ¿](?:(?!(?:[- ]{2,}|NOM\-059\-SEMARNAT))[A-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚÑ:;¿?()\-+. ,]){9,}(?<=[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÑ?]))(?![a-z])
```

Formatted:

```
 (?<! [A-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚÑ:;¿?()\-+.,] )             # ASSERT - Dont start in the middle of anything
 (                                            # (1 start)
      (?!                                          #  ASSERT - The start cannot be this phrases (add more)
           (?: NOM-059-SEMARNAT )
      )
      [A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÑ¿]                                 # Starts with a letter
      (?:
           (?!                                          # ASSERT - The body cannot contain this phrase  (add more)
                (?: [- ]{2,} | NOM\-059\-SEMARNAT )
           )
           [A-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚÑ:;¿?()\-+. ,] 
      ){9,}

      (?<= [A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÑ?] )                          # ASSERT - Ended with a letter
 )                                            # (1 end)
 (?! [a-z] )                                  #  ASSERT - Not a forward lower case when previous upper case that probably starts a sentence
```

Or, same but uses hex for extended ascii

```
 # (?<![A-Z0-9\x{C1}\x{C9}\x{CD}\x{D3}\x{DA}\x{D1}:;\x{BF}?()\-+.,])((?!(?:NOM-059-SEMARNAT))[A-Z\x{C1}\x{C9}\x{CD}\x{D3}\x{DA}\x{D1}\x{BF}](?:(?!(?:[- ]{2,}|NOM\-059\-SEMARNAT))[A-Z0-9\x{C1}\x{C9}\x{CD}\x{D3}\x{DA}\x{D1}:;\x{BF}?()\-+. ,]){9,}(?<=[A-Z\x{C1}\x{C9}\x{CD}\x{D3}\x{DA}\x{D1}?]))(?![a-z])


 (?<!
      [A-Z0-9\x{C1}\x{C9}\x{CD}\x{D3}\x{DA}\x{D1}:;\x{BF}?()\-+.,] 
 )
 (                                            # (1 start)
      (?!
           (?: NOM-059-SEMARNAT )
      )
      [A-Z\x{C1}\x{C9}\x{CD}\x{D3}\x{DA}\x{D1}\x{BF}] 
      (?:
           (?!
                (?: [- ]{2,} | NOM\-059\-SEMARNAT )
           )
           [A-Z0-9\x{C1}\x{C9}\x{CD}\x{D3}\x{DA}\x{D1}:;\x{BF}?()\-+. ,] 
      ){9,}

      (?<=
           [A-Z\x{C1}\x{C9}\x{CD}\x{D3}\x{DA}\x{D1}?] 
      )
 )                                            # (1 end)
 (?! [a-z] )
```

Comment: This solution works very well for me.  It is much more complex than I expected or could understand in my few days of studying regularexpressions, but is certainly very nice and educational!!!!  Thank you very much sln.

Comment: However, I didn't understand why my original RE failed the way it did.